# Retrieving longitude and latitude of more than one location

Tags: python, geolocation, foursquare

How can I get longitude and latitude of more than one place? I am trying to get the coordinates of 15 boroughs of Toronto. I've tried

```
address = ['Toronto Canada', 'East York', 'Davenport', 'Eglinton', 'Etobicoke', 'Toronto-Danforth']
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="foursquare_agent")
location = geolocator.geocode(address)
lat = location.latitude
lng = location.longitude
print(lat, lng)
```

The above returns: *AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute* 'latitude'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single `geocode()` query will search for a single location. To find more than one location, you need to run it in a loop.

```py
city = 'Toronto, Canada'
boroughs  = ['East York', 'Davenport', 'Eglinton', 'Etobicoke', 'Toronto-Danforth']
for borough in boroughs:
    address = borough + ', ' + city
    location = geolocator.geocode(address)
    lat = location.latitude
    lng = location.longitude
    print(address, lat, lng)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you've passed the wrong type to `geolocator.geocode`, which takes queries as either `dict` (used for structured queries) or `str`, while you were trying to pass a Python list.

See the GeoPy doc: https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#nominatim

So a straightforward, though not necessarily efficient method for you to obtain the information you want would be to just pass each borough encoded as a string to your geolocator instance individually. Something like the following should work:

```
# your usual imports and data assigments

locations = [geolocator.geocode(borough) for borough in address]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(locations)
---
[Location(Toronto, Golden Horseshoe, Ontario, M6K 1X9, Canada, (43.653963, -79.387207, 0.0)),
 Location(East York, Toronto—Danforth, East York, Toronto, Golden Horseshoe, Ontario, M4J 2G9, Canada, (43.6913391, -79.3278212, 0.0)),
 Location(Davenport, Scott County, Iowa, USA, (41.5236436, -90.5776368, 0.0)),
 Location(Eglinton, County Londonderry, Northern Ireland, BT47 3GY, United Kingdom, (55.0266097, -7.176451, 0.0)),
 Location(Etobicoke, Toronto, Golden Horseshoe, Ontario, Canada, (43.67145915, -79.5524920661167, 0.0)),
 Location(Toronto—Danforth, Old Toronto, Toronto, Golden Horseshoe, Ontario, Canada, (43.6789439, -79.3448597, 0.0))]
```

And from here, you should be able to obtain the latitudes, longitudes and whatever else you need from this list of `Location` objects.

Also note that "Davenport" and "Eglinton" clearly wasn't unambiguous enough, so you might want to specify "Davenport, Toronto" and so on.

Final note: the `geocode` method of the `Nominatim` class does have an optional argument `exactly_one` (`True` by default), so perhaps there does exist some way for you to get the geocoded locations of your entire list of different addresses with a single method invocation, but I didn't really look into how to do that (if it indeed is even possible), as I've never used GeoPy nor am I familiar with the subject of geocoding myself.

BTW, I'm from Toronto too, so I know all these places you mentioned :D